# Conceptual problems in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I am studying measure theory as a graduate student. I have studied the theory up to integration. Now I want to test my concepts by doing some problems as the best way to learn a topic is to do problems. However, I do not find any book that has nice and challenging problems on measure theory. Can someone suggest a book for problems in measure theory?

I have already tried Sheldon Axler and Royden, but neither suited my taste.

Comment: What did you dislike about the mentioned books?

Comment: @PhoemueX The problems are not conceptual.